# iphone. making UITextView but won't make it visible

Tags: iphone, delegates, uitextview

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
```

I need textview(editable) in my view controller.

so I set protocol ,

and also, IB to the file's owner, too. (I don't know, is it unnecessary?)

And my .m file.... viewDidLoad..

```
_textView = [[UITextView alloc]init];
[_textView setFrame:CGRectMake(8, 110, 304, 82)];
[_textView setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
_textView.editable = YES;
//[textView setText:@"hdgffgsfgsfgds"];// if uncommented, this actually visible...

[self.view insertSubview:_textView atIndex:2];
```

So far, it's working. But I want these methods to run...

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{


    if([_textView.text length] == 0)
    {
        _textView.text = @"Foobar placeholder";
        _textView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        _textView.tag = 0;
    }
}
```

But after build, my textview is still empty.

What did I wrong?

Comment: _textView.delegate = self; write this line. no need to IBOutlet if your not put your control in .XIB file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the delegate to your textview, try with this:

```
_textView.delegate = self;
```

On the other hand,

```
textViewDidChange
```

Will only work when you change your text, if you want to place a text in the textview, you can do:

```
 _textView.text = @"Foobar placeholder";
        _textView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        _textView.tag = 0;
```

In your **ViewdidLoad**

Comment: You're right! There was a logic problem...I guess. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When synthesizing the textView, do you do it like `@synthesize textView = _textView` so that you can use the underscored name? Usually the underscored one is used only in the setter/getter methods (for instance when overriding them).

Note that

> The text view calls this method in response to user-initiated changes to the text. This method is not called in response to programmatically initiated changes.

This is from Apple's documentation for the method you are using. This means if you are changing the text through the code, the method will not get fired.

Comment: so, I guess property to textfield is unnecessary, I assume?

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting [textView setText:@"hdgffgsfgsfgds"] to in turn invoke textViewDidChange:? Calling setText will not automatically invoke the textViewDidChange:.